# Refresh jquery form after submission not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

For one of my websites, I  am designing a HTML form with jquery and PHP for sending the data through email. 
The Jquery, checks for the empty /blank fields and sends alerts for each filed. 
Once the form is submitted with  full data, it  sends success alert and send the input data through PHP.
Till this point the code works fine.

Once the data is submitted & success alert is shown,  I want the html form to be refreshed / reloaded. 
But this this not happening, as the form remains with the pre-entered data.
Kindly help me in this please.  My Jquery & HTML form is given below.

JQUERY-CODE (with google libs 2.2)

**JQUERY CODE**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#submit").click(function() {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();
        $("#returnmessage").empty(); // To empty previous error/success message.
        // Checking for blank fields.
        if (name == '') {
          alert(" Please fill your name");
        } else if (email == '') {
          alert("Please fill your email");
        } else if (message == '') {
          alert("Please Fill message");
        } else { alert("Your form submitted. We will contact you soon.");
          $.post("xxx.php", { // To php file.
            name: name,
            email: email,
            message: message
          }, function(data) {
            $("#returnmessage").append(data);
            if (data == "Your form submitted. We will contact you soon.") {
              $("#form")[0].reset(); // To reset form fields on success.
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
```

**HTML FORM CODE:**

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="  ">
  <h4>FEED-BACK FORM</h4>
  <p id="returnmessage"></p>
  <label>Name:  </label>
  <input type="text" id="name" /><br>
  <label>Email:  </label>
  <input type="text" id="email" /><br>
  <label>Message:  </label>
  <input type="text" id="message" /><br>
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: console log your post response and check what your response come from your xxx.php.

Comment: Try trimming the response before checking `if ($.trim(data) == "....")`

Comment: show your xxx.php file source code.

Comment: PHP CODE:   'if (count($_POST) == 0)
  die("Need to POST");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$email_body ="Dear sir,\n".
"Name: $name\n". 
"Email: $email\n".
"Message:    $message\n";

//Email sending to
$email_from = 'xxx@xxx.xxx';
$email_subject = "my-form";
$to = "xxx@xxxx.xxx";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

//Send the email!
if (mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers))
  die("Success");
else
  die("Failed");'

Answer (score 2):

check below js

```
 if (data == "Your form submitted. We will contact you soon.") {
        document.getElementById('form').reset(); // To reset form fields on success.
```

}

Or

```
 if (data == "Your form submitted. We will contact you soon.") {       
    $('#form').find("input[type=text]").val(""); // To reset form fields on success.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can clear the input fields by setting its value to `""`

```
 $("#name").val("");
$("#email").val("");
$("#message").val("");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely with your `if` statement. The line `$("#form")[0].reset();` is correct, move it above the `if` statement to see it working.

Comment: does not need to move from if statement. Remove one =  if you use == it will check the datatype that's why it's not working.

if (data = "Your form submitted. We will contact you soon.") {
              $("#form")[0].reset(); // To reset form fields on success.
            }

Comment: Well, that's wrong. You cannot use single sign for equality in order to check if a statement is true or false, the single sign is used only for assigning values. My recommendation is to use only === when comparing stuff, since it compares the type and the value. When you try to compare different types of data, you should always get false. Try in the developer console those: "2" == 2 and "2" === 2 and see what's the result. In the first case, the compilers depends on the *type coercion*.

Comment: Yes sorry for the wrong response. I got this. Miss understand from here.

Comment: document.getElementById('form').reset(); its working for me.